# PyCharm CSS Editing: Disable auto-completion

Tags: css, autocomplete, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've look all around the internet and could not find a solution to my particular problem.

I'm using JetBrains PyCharm to edit CSS and for the life of me, can't figure out how to disable auto-completion.

For example, I have:

```
my_class {
   color
```

...and as soon as I hit tab, it fills:

```
my_class {
   color: #000;
```

which is not at all what I want.  I space my code differently, and I definitely don't want it to assume what color I want.

There are a lot of similar articles & Q/As out there, but many of them are dated, and none of the solutions work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable abbreviation expansion on hitting `Tab`, you can either disable **CSS Emmet** in **Settings | Editor | Emmet | CSS** or change `Tab` to a different key in **Settings | Editor | Emmet, Expand abbreviation with**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this gets me half of the way there - by not inserting a color - but still puts the colon in after I hit tab.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: this is just a way CSS completion works, this can't be configured

Comment: Wow, that's a bummer.  I'll mark this as accepted because it does eliminate the more annoying of the two issues.  Thanks.